# c++ strcpy SIGINT error

Tags: c++

I'm a student and I'm learning c++ language.

Here is my class;

```
class Book
{
    private:
        int location;
        char bookNum;
        char bookName[100];
}
```

I'm going to set string bookName "DEFAULT" by constructor

```
#include "Bookclass.h"

using namespace std;

Book::Book()
    :location(0), bookNum('0')
{
        strcpy(bookName, "DEFAULT");
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
}
```

and an error happened on strcpy in the constructor. When I used debugger(Dev c++), it said me that a SIGINT error happened. When I run it, it stop running.

Comment: *I'm a student and I'm learning c++ language* -- Looks more like `C` with classes to me.  Also, please post a [mcve], as all you posted is what your class looks like, not the actual code that instantiates and uses this class.

Comment: [Cannot duplicate](http://ideone.com/U6XTw7).

Comment: Re: "Here is my class:" -- no, not if the constructor code actually compiles. The declaration of the class has no constructor, so you cannot write `Book::Book()`. Post real code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the most amazing things about C++ is the standard library, which has solved all these cumbersome code issues. Consider replacing `bookName` with a [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string):

```
#include <string>

class Book
{
    Book();
private:
    int location;
    char bookNum;
    std::string bookName;
}

Book::Book()
    :location(0), bookNum('0'), bookName("DEFAULT")
{
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
}
```

`bookName` will be set to "DEFAULT" in the constructor, and reassigning it is as simple as `bookName = "new book name";`

Answer (score 0):

Your code works as intended on my PC, as such, the code is not the problem, your compiler and/or IDE is at fault here.

Look [here](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/signal.7.html), `SIGINT` means an interruption from keyboard.

I recommend changing your IDE to Visual Studio or NetBeans with C++.

Also, in all honesty this is C with classes, not C++.

Comment: C++ is a multi-paradigm language, one such paradigm is writing C-style code with classes .

Comment: Which is a bit counter-intuitive, isn't it? If you want C you use C, if you want C++ you use C++, mashing them up is wrong. I'm not saying you should combine C code with C++ code, I'm saying don't make a third party called C with classes.

Comment: And what if you want "C with classes" as you call it?

Comment: Then you made a terrible mistake down the road.